# Have a function in fortran return a reference that can be placed on the left-hand-side of an assignment

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95, fortran2003

As stated in the title, I want to *directly* modify data that I access through a pointer retrieved from a function. Having a reference returned by a function appearing on the l.h.s. of an assignment(=) is no issue in C++ but the following minimal example in fortran errors out:

```
module test_mod
  implicit none

  integer, target :: a=1, b=2, c=3 ! some member variables

contains

  function get(i)
    integer, pointer :: get
    integer, intent(in) :: i

    select case (i)
      case (1)
        get => a
      case (2)
        get => b
      case (3)
        get => c
    end select 
  end function get

end module test_mod

program test
  use test_mod
  implicit none
  integer, pointer :: i_p

  !> prints out 1 2 3
  print*, get(1), get(2), get(3)

  !> this is what I want but I get the error
  !> Error: 'get' at (1) is not a variable
  get(2) = 5

  !> this works but is not what I want
  i_p => get(2)
  i_p = 5

end program test
```

Is there any way to accomplish this behaviour; maybe I'm missing some attributes? I would like to bypass writing any setter routines such as

```
set(i,value)
```

since it should mimic the appearance of an array.
In my application, the member variables `a,b,c` are actually arrays of different size

```
a = [a1, a2, a3]
b = [b1, b2]
c = [c1]
```

and I want the getter `get(i,j)` to mimic a matrix of pointers

```
        j = 1   2   3

i = 1:   [[a1, a2, a3],
i = 2:    [b1, b2, XX],
i = 3:    [c1, XX, XX]]
```

wehre `XX` would be referencing to `null()`.

**Update:**
I am using gfortran (version 5.2.0) and the deployment machines would have only versions starting from 4.6.x and upwards. Therefore, the suggested fortran 2008 standard features are unfortunately not available to me. Is it possible to mimic the behaviour described above without having a compiler supporting it out of the box?

**Update 2:**
So I ended up implementing a structure as follows

```
type Vec_t
  integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: vec
end type Vec_t
type(Vec_t), allocatable, dimension(:), target :: data
```

which I initialise like this (my triangular matrix application I mention at the end)

```
allocate(data(max))
do i=1,max
  allocate(data(i)%vec(i))
end do
```

and I access & write to it through

```
print*, data(2)%vec(1)
data(2)%vec(1) = 5
```

which is not precisely what I was after but good enough for my application.

Comment: If you have a look at this link ( http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status ) only Cray has that feature implemented as of november 2014. So @nobody2100 you have to pay special attention to the version of the compiler that you are using.

Comment: [@francescalus Oh that's good news :D I was waiting for this more than 10 years maybe... ><]

Comment: @roygvib you should consider joining a compiler dev team :) instead of waiting for a feature for 10 years. Just kidding!

Comment: Regarding the update, it would be helpful to know what you have against your current workaround using a temporary pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what you want to do:

```
get(2)=5
```

and the error message

> Error: 'get' at (1) is not a variable

That looks pretty comprehensive: you can't do what you want.  Or, perhaps...

`get(2)` is indeed, under the rules of Fortran 2003, not a variable.  In Fortran 2003 a variable is given by the rules R601 and R603, which is a list of designators.

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

But look at Fortran 2008 and its definition of a variable.  Now a variable is either one of those same designators (or ones related to coarrays or complex parts), but it could also (C602 to R602) be a function reference which

> shall have a data pointer result.

This is summarized in the introduction of Fortran 2008, detailing the extensions over Fortran 2003, as

> A pointer function reference can denote a variable in any variable definition context.

`get(2)` is a reference to a function that has a data pointer result.  `get(2)` then may appear on the left-hand side of an assignment statement under the rules of Fortran 2008.

Alas, this interpretation of Fortran is [not widely supported](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2808700.2808703) by current compilers: at the time of answering just the Cray compiler.

This means that this answer is really saying that you have two options: switch compiler or wait until this feature is more widespread.  As both of these are likely impractical, you probably want another answer which gives something slightly more portable as a workaround.

<sup>I prefer my link to [that](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status) given by innoSPG, as although this latter is based on the former, the description of the appropriate field "Pointer functions - pointer function ref is a variable" is slightly more clear.  This is, though, a more accessible document and a viable alternative.</sup>

Comment: if the link that you prefer is the scientific paper on dl.acm.org, I will still go with mine for two reasons: 1) the paper is not free and I will not buy a paper just to know what is available or not; 2) the paper is by definition freezed, so it will not be updated while the link on fortranwiki will be updated later.

Comment: Those are reasonable points, and why I included the link you provided as an alternative.  Just in this case, the description "Pointer functions" is not immediately valuable.

Comment: And being frozen is good: when there's widespread support my answer is already out-dated ;).

Comment: Just for info - the syntax rules for *variable* in F2008 have changed subsequent to the initial publication of the standard - the rules now only permit a *function-reference* rather than the more general "reference to a function" for this case, in order to avoid a syntax ambiguity.

Comment: Yes.  The change was in F2008 corrigendum three.

Comment: For those interested, the reason was interp F08/0075 ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1951-N2000/N1987.txt and not everyone was satisfied with the fix ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1951-N2000/N1990.txt

Comment: Just tried the feature on Cray and it works there, but I cannot confirm gfortran 5. I think the rumour is a hoax. Does somebody have the latest trunk?

Comment: Thanks for checking, @VladimirF.  I may try to get gcc-trunk myself later, but if no one can confirm I'll remove that part.

Comment: @VladimirF I've checked with gcc 6.0 and it wasn't happy.

Comment: An update in 2017: gfortran 7.2 and intel 18.0 both support this